# Shared html template without server running

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

In my html page I want to add `footer` and `header` for all the pages

This app need to run by opening the file and not with server running.

I add to my code

```
fetch('shared/header.html')
.then((response) => {
    return response.text();
})
.then((html) => {
    document.body.innerHTML = html     
});
```

but I got cors error

```
Access to fetch at 'file:///D:/projects/javascriptApp/shared/header.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

How can I add shared html files into another file with vanilla javascript

Comment: as I said this file need open by the file location and the browser without any server running

Comment: Do you want any website to be able to read items from your documents folder or hdd?

Comment: @DreamBold — That's extremely dangerous and people doing that need to be very very careful not to start accessing third party websites with that setting turned on.

Comment: Yes, but what he's trying is dangerous as well

Comment: This app is not on the web, its a local project, I cannot run the command because I need any computer that run this html file will see the app with the header and footer, I need just something like Iframe